# Маска (регулярное выражение) на js, которая удаляет дефисы в начале и конце строки

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, есть ли такая маска в js. при помощи которой удаляются все тире в начале и конце строки. Вот мой пример, но он в удаляет ВСЕ тире из строки, а мне нужно только если он идет первым символом или последним

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/-/g,"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log("-Tupac-Shakur-".replace(/^-|-$/g,""))
```

Comment: Спасибо! А то я уже решил эту проблему через проверку if (this.value[0] == '-' || this.value[length - 1] == '-') {
       this.value = this.value.replace(/-/g,"")
     }

Comment: Оно же все равно тогда удалит со всей строки)

Comment: я уже понял, что тупанул

Comment: И да, если ответ решает ваш вопрос - нажмите галочку слева от него. И стрелочку вверх, если оказался полезным)

Comment: Спасибо большое